# Is it possible to set a sound from the raw folder as a ringtone without saving it to the sdcard?

Tags: android

My first android app was a soundboard, and it works great. When you set a sound as a ringtone, it saved the file to the ringtones folder. Someone took advantage of that and stole my sounds, and published their own soundboard with my sounds.

I dont want that to happen again with my next soundboard, so my question is:

is it possible to save a sound as a ringtone or notification without saving it?

EDIT: If this is not possible, I would like to know what I can do so I don't get my sound files stolen.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it possible seeing as there would be no reference to the sound when the ringtone was to go off.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://[package]/[res id]");
```